# Write a python script to read two parameters which are host and ports that I need to reach and print status?

Tags: python, scripting

Sample File:
cat ipaddressrouter.txt

'172.217.163.164' :80

'192.168.1.0' :22

Here is what I have tried but I'm getting an error:

```
import re
import socket
from multiprocessing import process
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
with open("/coder/Downloads/ipaddressrouter.txt",'r') as ip_add:
for eachline in ip_add:
    ip = eachline.strip().split(':')[0]
    a= ip.replace("'","")
    print(a)
    port = eachline.strip().split(':')[1]
    print(port)
    result = sock.connect_ex((str(a),int(port)))
    process(result)

ERROR- result = sock.connect_ex((str(a), int(port)))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Comment: remove the trailing white space from `ip address`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because of trailing white space in the `ip address`.
I have improved the code below to suit your use case.

```
import socket
from multiprocessing import process

with open("/coder/Downloads/ipaddressrouter.txt",'r') as ip_add:
    for eachline in ip_add:
        # since it's a list with 2 values, we can get the values in one go.
        ip, port = eachline.strip().split(':')

        # added here is '.strip()' to remove trailing white spaces.
        ip = ip.replace("'", "").strip() 

        print(ip, port)

        # a new socket would have to be created for each ip and port
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        result = sock.connect_ex((str(ip), int(port)))

        # closing the socket once done.
        sock.close()
    
        print("RESULT", result)
```